# Excel Add-In: addRowsAsync does not work after deleteAllDataValuesAsync in Office for Mac v16

Tags: javascript, office-js

We have create a new Add-in for Ms Office Excel. It requests data from our API and loads data to a table on the excel sheet.
It is not working on Office for Mac. I am testing in the version 16.26. It failed when we tried to get approved to the Windows store, however it has passed all the other platforms, including Excel Online in Safari.

I have narrow down the problem to not being able to do a addRowsAsync after having done a deleteAllDataValuesAsync. 
After doing deleteAllDataValuesAsync, it is like I no longer can reach the table. If I comment out deleteAllDataValuesAsync, the table gets loaded with data. This of course only works fine for the first time.
After deleteAllDataValuesAsync, I can't even access 'this' anymore on the callback, I can work around that, but it still does not load the table.

```
this.dataBinding.deleteAllDataValuesAsync({},() => 
{
    this.addDataToTable(data, curveDefinitions, filteredArray, dateFormat, userNumberFormat);
});

addDataToTable(data, curveDefinitions, filteredArray, dateFormat, userNumberFormat) 
{
    var firstRowToTransport = 0;
    var firstChunck = true;
    Office.context.document.bindings.getByIdAsync(
        this.dataBinding.id,
        asyncResult => 
        {
            this.dataBinding = asyncResult.value;
            this.transportChunkwiseToExcel(
                data, curveDefinitions, filteredArray, firstRowToTransport, firstChunck);
        }
    );
}
```

I have no error message even when debugging with safari

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a silly answer but could it be the extra comma after firstChunk?

```
this.dataBinding.deleteAllDataValuesAsync({},() => 
{
    this.addDataToTable(data, curveDefinitions, filteredArray, dateFormat, userNumberFormat);
});

addDataToTable(data, curveDefinitions, filteredArray, dateFormat, userNumberFormat) 
{
    var firstRowToTransport = 0;
    var firstChunck = true;
    Office.context.document.bindings.getByIdAsync(
        this.dataBinding.id,
        asyncResult => 
        {
            this.dataBinding = asyncResult.value;
            this.transportChunkwiseToExcel(
                data, curveDefinitions, filteredArray, firstRowToTransport, firstChunck);
        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that was just me trying to copy a more simplified version of the code, but thanks anyway